# Set-RunOnce run ps1 file from changing usb drive letter

Tags: powershell, cmd, automation, runonce

So I am using this Powershell script: Set-RunOnce https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/WindowsImageConverter/1.0/Content/Set-RunOnce.ps1

When I put the driveletter hardcoded in (E:\ServerInstall.ps1) it works like a charm.
But I want to be sure this script can **run from any drive letter the USB gets plugged into**.

> How can I get this changing drive letter in the registry?

I first tried it with *-ExecutionPolicy Bypass*, but that didn't change much either.

I also tried this:

> $getusb = Get-WmiObject Win32_Volume -Filter "DriveType='2'" .
> .\Set-RunOnce.ps1 Set-RunOnce -Command
>
> '%systemroot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe `
> -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File $getusb.Name\ServerInstall.ps1'
>
> -->
> $getusb.Name\ServerInstall.ps1 ended being hardcoded in the registry, but it didn't know what
> $getusb.name was, so the script didn't launch.

```
. .\Set-RunOnce.ps1
Set-RunOnce -Command '%systemroot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe `
-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File (wmic logicaldisk where drivetype=2)
ServerInstall.ps1'
```

Comment: Are you wanting to cause something to run each time the USB device is plugged into the machine?

Comment: You are not showing us what the `ServerInstall.ps1` script does. You should perform the `(wmic logicaldisk where drivetype=2)` stuff in there and not put it in as part of the commandline. See the example on https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/WindowsImageConverter/1.0/Content/Set-RunOnce.ps1

Comment: Use `"$($getusb.DriveLetter)\ServerInstall.ps1"` instead of `$getusb.Name\ServerInstall.ps1`. Also consider that `$getusb` could be an array if more USB disks are plugged in…

Comment: Why is the question tagged with `cmd` which is the Windows command processor used for processing Windows batch files. `cmd.exe` cannot execute PowerShell commands. `PowerShell.exe` is a completely different script interpreter. On using a batch file to run `PowerShell.exe` on double clicking on batch file on USB drive it would be possible to pass the drive of storage location of batch file as argument to PowerShell with `%~d0` which expands on execution to drive letter and colon. Run in a cmd window `call /?` for help. Argument 0 is always the batch file itself.

Comment: @Mofi once it is in the registry it uses the cmd code, and not powershell code. Once I run it it gets hardcoded in the registry, and it stays "$($getusb.DriveLetter)\ServerInstall.ps1", it doesn't get a drive letter

Answer (score 0):

The [Set-RunOnce](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/WindowsImageConverter/1.0/Content/Set-RunOnce.ps1) function is really easy to understand and simple to adjust.
I would suggest creating a derived function of your own to do what you want and use that instead:

```
function Set-RunOnceForUSB {
    # get the driveletter from WMI for the first (possibly only) USB disk
    $firstUSB   = @(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk | Where-Object {$_.DriveType -eq 2} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DeviceID)[0]
    # or use:
    # $firstUSB = @(Get-WmiObject Win32_Volume -Filter "DriveType='2'" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DriveLetter)[0]

    # combine that with the name of your script file to create a complete path
    $scriptPath = Join-Path -Path $firstUSB -ChildPath 'ServerInstall.ps1'

    # create the command string. use double-quotes so the variable $scriptPath gets expanded
    $command = "%systemroot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File $scriptPath"

    # next, add this to the registry same as the original Set-RunOnce function does
    if (-not ((Get-Item -Path HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce).Run )) {
        New-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce' -Name 'Run' -Value $command -PropertyType ExpandString
    }
    else {
        Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce' -Name 'Run' -Value $command -PropertyType ExpandString
    }
}
```